# How do I re-link the video of a project when editing on a different computer?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

[image]I know this is asked a lot but the answers i found haven't worked. I recently made a speech on a different laptop using blender 2.78 and then i sent the file to myself in an email and downloaded it onto my macbook pro. But for some reason when i try and watch the video in blender nothing is appearing. I've been trying to rebuild the proxies and everything else but nothing is working. I have audio in it as well that's not playing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggest you copy the video to a local drive and re-load. At the moment your link is to somewhere relative with lots of ...//././... and I am going to guess that is confusing matters.

Comment: If you are copying your files across different operating systems the paths to access them are probably messed up, make sure that you point to the correct file using the **strip input** path.

Answer (score -2):

Yu could try packing it into the blend file. I dont have 2.7x anymore but I think it is File->External Data->Pack All Into .blend

Comment: Video files can't be packed